# Image zooming to pointer position on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to zoom a image (map image) on moving(draggable) a pointer over it.
I have added the codes in the jsfiddle below, click on search and drag that flag.
So on dragging that flag and moving it over the map i want the map to be zoomed to that place.

http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/WZEna/2/

the map image is in the

`<div id="map"></div>`

Editing the jsfiddle for solution will be very much helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope your images are a bit larger than these in your fiddle?

Comment: Ya they are larger images ! 
I have contained them inside the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `stop`-callback from `draggable` and zoom-in your `#xyz`-image then:

Something like this (that's not perfect, but you can play a bit around with it):

```
$("#pointer").draggable({
    stop: function() {
        $("#xyz").css({
            transform: "scale(2)"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/WZEna/3/
I tried that 
Its zooming the image but where ever i place the flag same zoom is happening ! Its not zooming to place where i place the flag !! 
anyway voted up for the help :)

Comment: Just play a bit around to figure it out, if you stuck nevertheless come back and share your code and problem again ;)